# Memory is not released and out of memory exceptions in Kubernetes pod with app handling byte arrays

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes

We have a .NET Worker deployed in Kubernetes container and that worker deals with files of size ranging from 15KB-1MB we are using byte arrays through out the API to store the file content. We are noticing after sending 100 - 200 requests to the API the memory spikes up to 700 MB and stays there (the max allocated memory for the pod is 2GB) and if we continue that after certain point of time we used to get out of memory issues. Is the large byte arrays has problems to be quickly garbage collected?

Comment: Your code is adding references to the data.  The GC will not release the memory until all reference are removed.

Comment: Are you saying there is a memory leak? Can you please elaborate? I dont see any static or singleton objects referencing these byte arrays.

Comment: If the array is larger than 85,000 bytes it's going to go on the large object heap, and that heap never gets compacted, so you might see memory fragmentation issues.

Comment: Possible.  It is not the bytes that is causing the leaks.  You data is being deserialized in to classes.  The class data are accessed ByRef.  So until you dispose the classes and any object referencing the classes the memory is not gong to be disposed.  See : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/